# How to make a phone call from a webview link in zamarin

Tags: android, webview, xamarin

I can't figure out how to make a phone call in xamarin from a link inside a webview. Seems like I don't understand intents and activities correctly because I am putting StartActivity in the wrong place and the compiler says it does not exist in the current context. Aside from that error, am I even close to being correct in my code or am I missing stuff? I'm trying to catch if a hyperlink click in the webview is a phone number and if it is, launch the phone. Any help for a nube would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
using System;
using Android.Webkit;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Text;
using Android.Net;

namespace bobo
{
[Activity (Label = "bobo", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        var webview = new WebView(this);
        webview.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        webview.Settings.SetGeolocationEnabled(true);
        webview.SetWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        webview.SetWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient(this));
        SetContentView(webview);
    }
}

public class MyWebViewClient : WebViewClient
{

    public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, string url)
    {
        if (url.StartsWith("tel:")) { 
            var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(url);
            var intent = new Intent (Intent.ActionDial, uri);
            StartActivity(intent); 
        }
        else if(url.StartsWith("http:") || url.StartsWith("https:")) {
            view.LoadUrl(url);
        }
        return true;  
    }
}

public class MyWebChromeClient : WebChromeClient
{
    private readonly Context _context;

    public MyWebChromeClient(Context context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: How are you getting a reference to `StartActivity` in the `MyWebViewClient` class without passing a reference to the MainActivity class ?

Answer (score 0):

If it is not a http/https link, just launch it with Action_View. Android will take care of the rest.

```
Intent oURLIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(oURLIntent);
```